# Get raw input from command line (ignore shell meta characters)

Tags: bash, input

Is there any way to read raw text from `stdin` before it is expanded or before the shell does anything to it? Say I wanted to run a script where a user enters a string which is then printed out, how can I get the following behavior:

```
$ sh test.sh
Please enter a string:
***<><><||&&*&$PATH

You entered:
***<><><||&&*&$PATH
```

Is there any way to implicitly surround the text with `''` or escape all meta characters even if the user does not?

Comment: Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)  In *most* cases, there should be no good reason to use the shell for what you are doing.  Perhaps you can, but the shell is *not* a general-purpose programming language.  Much like Excel macros are simply the wrong tool to use to attempt to prove or disprove the Riemann Hypothesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ read -r -p 'Please enter a string >>> ' var
$ printf '%q\n' "$var"
\*\*\*\<\>\<\>\<\|\|\&\&\*\&\$PATH
```

Comment: The `-r` is the magic option; see `help read`.

Comment: No, the magic is `%q`

Answer (score 0):

The expansion, if any, is happening when you print, not when you read. (as Giles said, the magic is in the %q. But even echo "$var" is not expanded).
Read gets all the literal characters into the variable, except backslash. 
Echo of the bare variable is expanded. 
Echo of the variable in a "quote" string is not expanded:

xxmetac.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
read str
echo you entered:
echo $str
echo "$str"
```

test:

```
$ ls
file1 file2 file3

$ xxmetac.sh
*
you entered:
file1 file2 file3
*
```

Also most shell metacharacters are not special even when echoed. Probably only the file-globbing ones:

```
*?[-]{,}
```

Not special:

```
!#@$^%()|<>

$ xxmetac.sh
>
you entered:
>
>

$ xxmetac.sh
|
you entered:
|
|

$ xxmetac.sh
@$^%()|<>
you entered:
@$^%()|<>
@$^%()|<>
```

They are special *on the command line*

```
$ !#@$^%()|<>
@$^%()|<>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```